# TFM_SBSFU_Boot with Azure RTOS

Tags: bootloader, azure-rtos

I am trying to use Azure RTOS on STM32U585 board with ST's TFM_SBSFU_Boot. Everything seems fine until _tx_thread_schedule(); call and after that I observe no thread running(though thread creation and everything else was successful). Unfortunately I can't not do step debugging kind of thing also here. Need help.

Tried a few things, but no success.